# How can I describe a nameless query parameter with Swagger?

Tags: json, rest, http, swagger, swagger-ui

I have an API endpoint that responds to POST requests with a query parameter of the form:

```
json_string = '{"items":%20[{"name":%20"chicken",%20"quantity":%201,%20"basePrice":%20499,%20"priceWithModifiers":%20499},%20{"name":%20"soda",%20"quantity":%201,%20"basePrice":%20399,%20"priceWithModifiers":%20399}],%20"salesTax":%20{"id":%20"T8JKFEVBE6F30",%20"name":%20"Sales%20Tax",%20"rate":%20900000,%20"isDefault":%20true},%20"orderType":%20{"id":%20"ZJQ5ND5FZAAVP",%20"taxable":%20true,%20"isDefault":%20true,%20"filterCategories":%20false,%20"isHidden":%20false,%20"hoursAvailable":%20"BUSINESS",%20"isDeleted":%20false}}'
```

So, the complete url is "endpoint/?{json_string}". I have tried to use content -> application/json -> schema to describe the parameter as a string, but since I must give the parameter a name, there will always be an unwanted "*=*" somewhere in the query parameter.
*I do not want to rewrite the api itself*.

You can create a similar string in Javascript with

```
const my_dict = {"items": [5,6,7], "SalesTax": {"id": "foobar"}, "orderType": {"id": "Takeout"}}

query_param = JSON.stringify(my_dict)
```

or in Python

```
import json
my_dict = {"items": [5,6,7], "SalesTax": {"id": "foobar"}, "orderType": {"id": "Takeout"}}
query_param = json.dumps(my_dict)
```

Comment: It's not a query parameter if it doesn't follow the `=`-delimited key value pattern in the URL. Given that, and the fact that you are not interested in changing the API itself, I don't think you'll be able to describe this with Swagger. It's not a standard format AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I decided to rewrite the api to add a single parameter *metaData* and pass that the JSON string so that it would work with Swagger. it would be nice if name were not required, though :/

Comment: Rather than fight against a standard, I would just name it `json`, ie `endpoint?json={json_string}`, and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you wouldn't use a POST with a request body? What's the purpose of maintaining the json string in the query? The url is character limited to 2048. If your json string grows past this number, you'll have much bigger problems. The other advantage is you don't need to encode a request body.

```
POST /endpoint HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json

{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "chicken",
            "quantity": 1,
            "basePrice": 499,
            "priceWithModifiers": 499
        },
        {
            "name": "soda",
            "quantity": 1,
            "basePrice": 399,
            "priceWithModifiers": 399
        }
    ],
    "salesTax": {
        "id": "T8JKFEVBE6F30",
        "name": "Sales Tax",
        "rate": 900000,
        "isDefault": true
    },
    "orderType": {
        "id": "ZJQ5ND5FZAAVP",
        "taxable": true,
        "isDefault": true,
        "filterCategories": false,
        "isHidden": false,
        "hoursAvailable": "BUSINESS",
        "isDeleted": false
    }
}
```

This is defined as a JSON Schema as follows:

```json
{
    "$id": "itemWithPricing",
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "quantity": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "basePrice": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "priceWithModifiers": {
                        "type": "number"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "salesTax": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "rate": {
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "isDefault": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                }
            }
        },
        "orderType": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "taxable": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "isDefault": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "filterCategories": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "isHidden": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "hoursAvailable": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "isDeleted": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your OpenAPI description

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.1.0",
    "info": {},
    "servers": [],
    "paths": {
        "/endpoint": {
            "post": {
                "summary": "create a new item with pricing",
                "parameters": [],
                "requestBody": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/requestBodies/itemsWithPricing"
                },
                "responses": {
                    "201": {
                        "description": "Created",
                        "headers": {
                            "location": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "itemsWithPricing": {
                "$id": "itemWithPricing",
                "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "items": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "uniqueItems": true,
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "quantity": {
                                    "type": "number"
                                },
                                "basePrice": {
                                    "type": "number"
                                },
                                "priceWithModifiers": {
                                    "type": "number"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "salesTax": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "rate": {
                                "type": "number"
                            },
                            "isDefault": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "orderType": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "taxable": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "isDefault": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "filterCategories": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "isHidden": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "hoursAvailable": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "isDeleted": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "requestBodies": {
            "itemsWithPricing": {
                "content": {
                    "application/json": {
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/itemsWithPricing"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "required": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```